# Ubuntu 18.10 NVIDIA drivers boot to blank login screen

Tags: nvidia

How can I get to a shell so I can resolve this issue or simply stop the nvidia drivers loading?

Recovery modes still 'boot' to a blank screen.

The machine is pingable but I can't get in remotely either via SSH.

Any suggestions welcome. I've tried several ideas from around the web but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Use a live USB and chroot into your machine installation. Make sure to replace `sdX1` with the partition that contains your root installation on your machine.

```
sudo -s
mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt 
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

```
chroot /mnt
apt remove nvidia* --purge
```

**If nouveau drivers are needed to be disabled at boot:**

If not, skip to `umount /dev`

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`

Ctrl + O to write out, press enter to save, Ctrl + X to exit back to terminal.

```
update-grub
umount /dev
umount /proc
umount /sys
```

```
shutdown -r now
```

Remove install media, press enter etc. etc.

Note: this is what you may want that line in GRUB to look like.

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"

Comment: Can someone comment how to use `sed -i` to append `nouveau.modeset=0` to the correct line? Or should a different command be used (for ex. appending after splash) if GRUB lines are different per distro?

Comment: Is it possible to boot off my LIVE Ubuntu 18.10 DVD instead? There is no option to do so within GRUB

Comment: Yes, boot off your live DVD/USB (they are basically the same since your RAM is used as a temporary storage) and select 'Try Ubuntu without installing'. All these commands should be run in terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) while in the desktop environment of your live DVD or USB. None of details listed should be executed in GRUB. If you like I can post images of the process.

Comment: Ubuntu is running on my iMAC 2013 so there's no option to 'Try ubuntu' without installing. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll use a VirtualBox to attempt to replicate what you would see. Give me a moment to download 18.10 as I have the 18.04 ISO. When you boot up the live DVD, do you see an option to 'Try Ubuntu' on the left?

Comment: The DVD drive is connected to my iMAC 2013 model with the Ubuntu 18.10 DVD inserted. I used to be able to press the OPTION button button on the IMac and it would should the HDD partitions, one for OSX, one for Win10, then DVD

Comment: Hi Everyone,

Here's a list of tasks I'm going to try to get out of the black screen issue:

At BLACK SCREEN (GUI GDM3)

PRESS ENTER to prompt for password
enter password
Wait 60 seconds
CTRL-ALT-T to open terminal

sudo telinit 3
enter password
cursor top left corner
Press ALT-F1 gets to login prompt

sudo reboot now
enter password

sudo shutdown -r now
enter password

sudo update-grub
enter password

sudo shutdown -r now
enter password

Any other ideas most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue: after installing Ubuntu 18.10 and the proprietary NVIDIA drivers I was presented with a black screen, no cursor, WIFI was working, CTL-ALT-F1 etc to TTYs returned nothing. OSX, Windows 10 nor Linux would boot.

Solution:

Boot Grub, press ‘E’ to edit the default Ubuntu grub boot config

Append the following command to the line in grub that starts with linux /boot/vmlinuz*

systemd.unit=emergency.target

press F10 to boot

This will get you to a terminal prompt.

Next you need to mount the root file system in read-write mode with:

Mount –o remount,rw /

Using vi edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf 
And uncomment the line #WaylandEnable=false

sudo reboot now
Boot Linux as normal and it should get you to the GDM3 login prompt.

Login and CTRL-ALT-T to open a terminal and install rEFInd and reboot
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install refind
sudo reboot now

You should be presented with the rEFInd splash screen. Try and start your Linux, OSX or your Windows OS.

My Windows 10 OS would not start (OS not found). I had to power off/on the iMAC and then read through the following Microsoft KB:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/3103656/an-operating-system-wasn-t-found-error-when-booting-windows

For my IMac the resolution is as follows:

Insert the Windows 10 DVD and chose the DVD in rEFInd.
Once you have reached the setup screen  press the SHIFT + F10 keys to bring up the Command Prompt.
Type in dir c:
This returned my C: drive directories, I then typed in:
bcdboot C:\Windows /S C:
The message Boot files successfully created must be shown before you can continue.
Type:
diskpart
list disk
sel disk C
list vol
sel vol C
active
You should get a confirmation that the volume has been successfully set as active. If you don’t get the confirmation, it means that either the disk is set to GPT (not MBR), or there is a problem with the disk. Make sure you are working with the right disk.
Type: exit and press Enter.
Reboot the device

In rEFInd choose BOOTCAMP and my Windows 10 OS booted normally.